# Characterization of the transcendentals over a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, galois-theory, algebraic-curves

I'm studying [Algebraic Function Fields and Codes book from Henning Stichtenoth](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540768777) and I didn't understand this remark in the first page:

[image]

I couldn't solve any part of the equivalence, I think maybe because I don't remember very well the Galois theory classes, if someone could help in this remark I would be very grateful.

I need help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is false, let $F/K$ be any algebraic extension. Then any $z\in F$ is algebraic and $F/K(z)$ has finite degree. Since this is a remark, perhaps they have a specific $F,K$ in mind, if so you should include that in your post so we know.

Comment: Dear @Adam, I'm guessing that, as you suggest, there is some context missing. The field $F$ is probably assumed to be an extension of $K$ of transcendence degree $1$.

Comment: Not surprisingly I own a copy of this book. Keenan's got it right. An umbrella assumption of transcendence degree one is made very early, because the author does not want to repeat it, and does not consider other kinds of function fields.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, @JyrkiLahtonen.

Comment: Furthermore, it is also assumed that $F/K$ is finitely generated. This prevents the possibility of a transcendental element $z$ such that $[F:K(z)]$ is infinite (even though it is algebraic by virtue of $F/K$ having transcendence degree one).

Comment: CAVEAT: My version of that book is the Universitext series book from 1993 - not the GTM series book (2. Auflage) from 2009. I am totally ignorant about the eventual differences between the two editions. I only now clicked the link (the titles are identical) as the OP gave the link in a different thread also (with content that did not ring a bell at all).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Jyrki's comment we can proceed. If $F/K(z)$ is algebraic, then $K(z)$ is of infinite degree, hence transcendental by definition since $[F:K]\le [F:K(z)][K(z):K]$ and we know $[F:K]=\infty$ and $[F:K(z)]<\infty$, by the finite generation and algebraic hypotheses it must be that $[K(z):K]=\infty$.

On the other hand, if $z\in F$ is transcendental, then $[K(z):K]=\infty$ and by definition of transcendence degree, the longest chain of pairwise infinite degree extensions we can have with initial field $K$ and final field $F$ is of length $1$, hence $K\subseteq K(z)\subseteq K(z, \alpha_1)\subseteq \ldots\subseteq K(z,\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\ldots,\alpha_k)$ must have $[K(z,\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_k):K(z)]<\infty$ for any $k$ and $\alpha_i\in F$ since the first inclusion has infinite degree. But since $F$ is finitely generated, $F=K(z,\alpha_1,\ldots, \alpha_n)$ so that the $\alpha_i$ must be algebraic over $K(z)$ since that first extension is infinite degree. Hence $F/K(z)=K(z,\alpha_1,\ldots, \alpha_n)/K(z)$ is algebraic.

Comment: What's the definition of transcendence degree? the definition of field extensions I know is $[F:K]=\dim_K(F)$ ($F$ a vector field over $K$)

Comment: @user42912 That's the definition of the ordinary degree of a field extension, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendence_degree for transcendence degree.

Comment: So my definition of degree is different than yours?

Comment: Degree is fine, transcendence degree you haven't said one. If this terminology doesn't look familiar to you from your book, you should provide context in your original post. I've never read this book so I have no idea if you're using some other definition.

Comment: I didn't understand, the book said _degree_ instead _transcendence degree_. I'm using the definition of degree extensions in Battacharya's book. There are two different definitions of degree extensions? I'm really confused.

Comment: If you look at the comments on your original post, we found that all transcendental extensions in your book have what is called "transcendence degree 1." The notion of a field degree and its transcendence degree are separate thing. The ordinary "degree" is just as you say:  the dimension as a vector space over the base field. The "transcendence degree" has to do with how many algebraically independent transcendentals you can adjoin to the field, which has nothing to do with dimension over the base field.

Comment: @user42912: Study [the Wikipedia article on transcendence degree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendence_degree). Hopefully that makes it clear. The concept is often not met in a first course on field extensions.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen So how do I know when the author are speaking of transcendental degree or "ordinary" degree, since the author doesn't write the word "transcendence"?

Comment: If he says "degree" he means ordinary degree. I only mentioned transcendence degree in my answer because you need it to prove what you're looking for.

Comment: Right, I'll add that in. I was assuming that was another context thing from the book since it was necessary and you didn't dispute it in your original clarification.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, I was confused, thanks.

Comment: I didn't understand why if $F/K$ is algebraic than $K(z)$ is infinite degree.

Comment: @user42912 do you mean $F/K(z)$?

Comment: yes I'm sorry, if $F/K(z)$ is algebraic than $K(z)$ is infinite degree.

Comment: @user42912 $F/K$ is transcendental, if $F=K(\{\alpha_i\}_i, z)$ with all $\alpha_i$ algebraic, then if $z$ is algebraic $F/K$ is algebraic, which is impossible:  it's transcendental. So $z$ must be transcendental.